# Node js. How to share an array between two functions? Is there any less complicated way

Tags: node.js, synchronization, atomic

I am very new to nodejs and stuck at a place where one function populates an array and the other reads from it.

Is there any simple construct to synchronize this.

Code looks something like Below

```
let arr = [];
let prod = function() {
    arr.push('test');
};

let consume = function() {
    process(arr.pop());
};
```

I did find some complicated ways to do it :(

Thanks alot for any help... ☺️

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? What do you mean by synchronize?

Comment: Hi, @kapil. Have you been able to solve your issue provided with the answers below?

Comment: Thanks @KidBinary, I have marked it solved :)

Comment: @kapil: Appreciate it, although it's more interesting to find out whether solution was correct : )

Comment: @KidBinary : Sure it is correct :) for my current requirement, and also I did realise that I could have used this approach at many other places in my project. Thanks (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By synchronizing you probably mean that push on one side of your application should trigger pop on the other. That can be achieved with not-so-trivial event-driven approach, using the NodeJS [Events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) module.

However, in simple case you could try another approach with intermediary object that does the encapsulation of array operations and utilizes the provided callbacks to achieve observable behavior.

```
// Using the Modular pattern to make some processor
// which has 2 public methods and private array storage
const processor = () => {
  const storage = [];

  // Consume takes value and another function
  // that is the passed to the produce method
  const consume = (value, cb) => {
    if (value) {
      storage.push(value);
      produce(cb);
    }
  };

  // Pops the value from storage and
  // passes it to a callback function
  const produce = (cb) => {
    cb(storage.pop());
  };

  return { consume, produce };
};

// Usage
processor().consume(13, (value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

This is really a noop example, but I think that this should create a basic understanding how to build "synchronization" mechanism you've mentioned, using observer behavior and essential JavaScript callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback to share data between two functions

```
function prod(array) {
  array.push('test1')
}

function consume() {
  prod(function (array) {
    console.log(array)
  })
}
```